# Is it worth adding an index on the second field for a query in MongoDB?

Tags: performance, mongodb, indexing

I have a MongoDB collection view which has 3 fields: userId, time, videoId.

Most of the time I will query the collection to get the time for a given userId and videoId.

Should I add 2 indexes, to userId and videoId, or is a single index on userId enough to make the query faster?

Comment: The most optimal index will contain the fields you most commonly use and within the order that narrows down results the most. I.e a "compound" index for both "userId" and "videoId" would be useful for the combination, but if you also query on just "videoId" and that is the second specified key to the compound index, then you would ideally want another index for just that field. Where "videoId" is first in the compound, searches on just that value can still use that index ( since the field is first ). It's all a trade-off, as more indexes require more write action on updating, and more space.

Comment: Thank you @BlakesSeven, that helps. 
Also I love it when people reply to more than just the question.